# Why do I get `Procedure or function expects parameter`?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, asp-classic

I'm inserting a row into a SQL Server 2005 database table from Classic ASP.

I get the following error:

> *Procedure or function 'replace_matl_form_insert' expects parameter '@matl_no',  which was not supplied.*

I am supplying the parameter. The types match, and I'm still getting that error. Here is the classic asp code which is used to insert

```
     set CMDInsForm = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
     CMDInsForm.ActiveConnection = CONN
     CMDInsForm.CommandText = "dbo.replace_matl_form_insert"

     set parm = CMDInsForm.CreateParameter ("matl_no", adChar, adParamInput, 8, Trim(matl_no))
     CMDInsForm.Parameters.Append parm
     For each X in CMDInsForm.Parameters
          Response.Write err_msg & X.Name & ":" & X.Value & "<BR>"
     Next

     CMDInsForm.Execute
```

As you can see, I cycle through the parameters and print out their name and value. The name `matl_no` and the correct value are printed.

Here is the section of the stored procedure which retrieves it.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[replace_matl_form_insert]
    (@matl_no char(8))
 AS [...]
```

I'm completely stumped. Does anybody have **any** suggestions on what it could be, or just take a shot in the dark? I don't care how crazy it sounds.

Comment: .CreateParameter ("@matl_no" does not work?

Comment: @bummi No, I ge the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need the "@" on the start of the parameter name:

```
set parm = CMDInsForm.CreateParameter ("@matl_no", adChar, adParamInput, 8, Trim(matl_no))
```

**EDIT**
Also, try setting the `CommandType` to `4` (which is `adCmdStoredProc`):

```
CMDInsForm.CommandType = 4
```

http://www.w3schools.com/ado/prop_comm_commandtype.asp

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the `@` in the parameter name. Try:

```
set parm = CMDInsForm.CreateParameter ("@matl_no", ...
```

Instead of :

```
set parm = CMDInsForm.CreateParameter ("matl_no", ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to send parameter to your SP (in some condition ) you can initialize a default value to your SP parameter like

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[replace_matl_form_insert]
    (@matl_no char(8)=NULL)
 AS [...]
```

by assigning NULL value to your parameter ,you willn't get this Error

```
Procedure or function 'replace_matl_form_insert' expects parameter '@matl_no', which was not supplied.
```